# make a Powershell script take only the first 10000 files it finds for this filter defined

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am trying to list me only the 10000 first files this script finds, but I can't find a way to make it  work.
The script looks like this :

```
$totalList = @()
Get-Item 'D:\tempfolder\*\' | % {
  $dir = $_.FullName
  $list = Get-ChildItem  $dir -recurse *.zip | sort modifyTime -desc | select -skip 2 
  $totalList = $totalList + $list;
}

$totalList = $totalList -take 10000
```

the -take 1000 doesn't work as expected, so how can I define a number of files it should find at maximum ?

Comment: You could try $totalList = $totalList | Select -First 10000

Comment: already tried, but you can't pipe that . thanks

Comment: sorry, it works. but only if i export the output in a file. strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can say:

```
$totalList = $totalList[0..9999]
```

Comment: works as well, but i have to export the output to .csv or something else. it's not displayed in my shell. Thank you